# как сменить динамический ip адрес oracle cloud

Tags: виртуальная-машина

Можно ли как-то менять выданный публичный ip адрес виртуальной машине в oracle cloud? Например в  microsoft azure это реализовано очень просто, присваиваешь машине dns имя, перезагружаешь машину и меняется ip адрес.